# How to loop through a list of predefined worksheets in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm learning VBA by trial, error and searching. Right now I have something like this:

```
For i = 1 To NewEntries

MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tnd, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(2, 3).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Date, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(2, 5).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Code, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 2).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Desc, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 3).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Price, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 4).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sprice, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 5).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Disc, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 6).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Payment, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 7).Value
MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Bank, example, 0) + 1) = ReportA.Cells(4 + i, 8).Value 
Next
```

How can I put the FOR loop inside something that loops through ReportA through ReportZ instead of copying this code block for each report?

Comment: Could you please share the full code to us?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Chr` with the ascii code.

```
dim a as long
For i = 1 To NewEntries
    for a = 65 to 90
        with worksheets("report" & chr(a))
             debug.print .Cells(2, 3).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tnd, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(2, 3).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Date, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(2, 5).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Code, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 2).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Desc, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 3).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Price, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 4).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sprice, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 5).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Disc, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 6).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Payment, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 7).Value
             MH.Cells(i + LastRow2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Bank, example, 0) + 1) = .Cells(4 + i, 8).Value 
        end with
    next a
next i
```

Comment: Can this be done referencing a list somewhere else? In case the reports are no longer named "ReportA" but "ReportJohn", "ReportDave" etc?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the right order for the two nested For ... Next loops; you might want to put the `i` loop inside the `a` loop.

Comment: Then you would build an array of worksheet names and loop through them.

Comment: Are they the only sheets in the workbook?  If every sheet needs that calculation you could use a `For...Each` code block to go through all sheets in the file.  You could ignore certain sheets using a `SELECT CASE` within the block.